# How can you kill only Chrome tabs from Windows task manager

Tags: google-chrome, task-manager

Similar to this question: [Associate a tab in Google Chrome with its process in task manager](https://superuser.com/questions/557999/associate-a-tab-in-google-chrome-with-its-process-in-task-manager)

But I would like to know how I can close tabs from task manager and only tabs, some of the chrome.exe processes will cause the entire google chrome to close. Sometimes I cannot use the in built manager because of chrome has freezed doing it from windows task manager is the only way. So I can see which processes are taking a lot of memory and close them but I want to only close them if it's a tab and won't close the entirety of the google chrome application.

Comment: If Chrome has crashed, closing one tab probably isn't going to fix it. Just set Chrome to start with your current session every time you open it, and then you can close it fully when it crashes.

Comment: @Zacharee1 yes that's exactly why I need it. It crashes because there are too many tabs and I have very little memory. So when it crashes, if chrome closes, when I reopen it and click "restore tabs" then it just freezes again. I have a small amount of time to interact with chrome before it freezes again, it would be easier to use windows task manager instead as it still works, laggy but operable.

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://superuser.com/questions/306714/how-to-kill-one-tab-of-google-chrome-using-pid

Comment: @Zacharee1 making it say "aw snap" is just fine

Comment: Well, I did some research and, from the two Google pages I looked through, there seems to be no way to do this besides actually using Chrome to find the PIDs. `SHIFT+Esc` and `about:memory` won't work if you can't use Chrome. I think you'll have to guess it if Chrome freezes and then check once you can.